# What does the "Prelude" prefix mean in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting to learn Haskell. The Prelude is [described](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html) as a default module:

> The Prelude: a standard module. The Prelude is imported by default into all Haskell modules

But this doesn't explain why [various documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/6.10-latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html) has "Prelude" as a prefix in REPL:

```
Prelude>
```

I've installed [the mingw version](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) via Chocolatey and my REPL shows "ghci" as a prefix, not "Prelude":

```
GHCi, version 9.2.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci>
```

The Prelude module is loaded though:

```
GHCi, version 9.2.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :browse! Prelude
-- imported via Prelude
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
...
```

Why do prefixes differ and what does "Prelude" mean in the interactive compiler?

Comment: It means it loaded the `Prelude`. If you `import Data.List` for example it will say `Prelude Data.List>`. It thus lists what modules are loaded.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but the Prelude module was loaded! updated the Q

Comment: yes, as of GHC-9.0, it does no longer list the loaded modules, and by default the `Prelude` is loaded, only if you pass an `-XNoImplicitPrelude` flag, it will not load the prelude. The fact that it changed to `ghci>` does not mean the prelude is no longer loaded, it just means they no longer list loaded modules, which was often not very convenient if you loaded 20 or more modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But this doesn't explain why various documentation has "Prelude" as a prefix in REPL.

Since [ghci-9.0](/questions/tagged/ghci-9.0) it has changed and shows the `ghci>` prompt.

Prior to [ghci-9.0](/questions/tagged/ghci-9.0), the prompt showed the modules that were loaded. For example if you import an module `Data.List`, it changes the prompt to:

```
$ ghci-8.6.5
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List>
```

and if we do not load the `Prelude` by specifying a `-XNoImplicitPrelude` flag, we get:

```
$ ghci-8.6.5 -XNoImplicitPrelude
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>
```

As of [ghci-9.0](/questions/tagged/ghci-9.0), it shows `ghci>` as prompt. Often if you had to work with a lot of modules the prompt was very long, and thus made it inconvenient to work with GHCi.

You can set the prompt to something else with `:set prompt "someprompt> "` for example:

```
$ ghci                                                                                                                                                                                      
GHCi, version 9.0.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :set prompt "someprompt> "
someprompt>
```

The prompt has some [speciale sequences](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt) to show some information as [@pedrofurla says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123345/what-does-the-prelude-prefix-mean-in-ghci/70123414?noredirect=1#comment123970140_70123414). If you want the old behavior back in newer versions of GHCi, then set the prompt to `%s>`  (and also do `:set prompt-cont "%s| "` for multiline prompts):

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.0.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :set prompt "%s> "
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List>
```

If you want your change to the prompt to persist into new GHCi sessions, then put the command in `~/.ghci` (creating it if it doesn't exist).

Comment: A nice reference for your answer: https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt.